# How to draw sequence diagram with a method call to another class

Tags: sequence-diagram

Consider this class:

```
class Writer {
    @Inject
    private SomeAPI remove;

    public void write(Item item) {
        remove(item);
    }
}
```

I want to create a sequence diagram for this where I also want to represent the write method. Is below SD correct? Got a bit confused.

[image: Initial thoughts]

I did this like below now after thinking for a while. Please let me know opinion on both.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several aspects to consider here:

Arrows describe messages or function calls (with parameters) from one entity to another and the corresponding response messages/return values. An arrow to the same lifeline represents a call within the same entity or a recursive call (see also [this helpful introduction](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorials/uml2/sequence-diagram.html)).

You can model loops or optional parts within the sequence by using [combined fragments](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html). However, error handling methods such as retrying are probably a general property of your system and not specific to this sequence. In fact, many people [advise against modeling exceptions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290410/how-to-show-retry-in-sequence-diagram) for better readablility of your diagrams.

Now assuming that the Writer's `write` method is called by a third object  (which is not quite clear to me from your question), the diagram should look like this:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. Removing "retries" will make it more streamlined. Also, I got the answer in the arrows which is same as what I did in my last diagram. Thank you.